# Adjusting spacing for the immediate next node and line in d3.js tree

Tags: d3.js

CodePen: https://codepen.io/cziagfko-the-scripter/pen/ExdBpZy?editors=1010

[image]

I am frustrated because every time I try, it adjusts the spacing for all nodes instead of just the next node.

My code:

```
const data = {
        name: "root",
        color: "pink",
        children: [
            {
                name: "One",
                color: "blue",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "A1",
                        color: "red",
                        description: "我是描述A1",
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: "AA1",
                                color: "green",
                                description: "我是描述AA1",
                                children: [

                                    {
                                        name: "BB1323BD3",
                                        color: "green",
                                        description: "我是描述AA3",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "BBSASDSA1323BD4",
                                        color: "yellow",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "BB1323BD5",
                                        color: "yellow",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "BB1323BD6",
                                        color: "yellow",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "BB3123BD7",
                                        color: "yellow",
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                            {
                                name: "AA2",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "AA3",
                                color: "green",
                                description: "我是描述AA3",
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                name: "Two",
                color: "cyan",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "C1",
                        color: "pink",
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: "BBBD1",
                                color: "green",
                                description: "我是描述AA1",

                            },
                            {
                                name: "BBBD2",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "BBBD3",
                                color: "green",
                                description: "我是描述AA3",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "BBBD4",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "BBBD5",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "BBBD6",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "BBBD7",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "TBBBD7",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "QBBBD7",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "BGSBBD7",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "BB99",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "43D7",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "B1237",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "BB43347",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        name: "D2",
                        color: "brown",
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: "D12",
                                color: "green",
                                description: "我是描述AA1",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "D22",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "D3",
                                color: "green",
                                description: "我是描述AA3",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "D4",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "D5",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "D6",
                                color: "yellow",
                            },
                            {
                                name: "D7",
                                color: "yellow",
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: "sB4B3D1",
                                        color: "green",
                                        description: "我是描述AA1",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "sB213BD2",
                                        color: "yellow",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "sB123BD3",
                                        color: "green",
                                        description: "我是描述AA3",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "sB141BD4",
                                        color: "yellow",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "sB141BD5",
                                        color: "yellow",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "sB142BD6",
                                        color: "yellow",
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "sB3453BD7",
                                        color: "yellow",
                                    },
                                ],
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    };
    // 建置 SVG
    const svg = d3
        .select('.chart')
        .attr('width', 1650)
        .attr('height', 800)
        .call(d3.zoom()
            .on('zoom', zoomed)
        )
        .on('dblclick.zoom', null)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(-300, 20)');

    // 建置樹圖 layout
    const hierarchyData = d3.hierarchy(data);
    const treeLayout = d3.tree().size([3000, 800 - 40]);
    const nodesData = treeLayout(hierarchyData);

    // 建置線
    const links = svg
        .selectAll('.link')
        .data(nodesData.links())
        .join('path')
        .attr('class', 'link')
        .attr('d', d3.linkVertical().x((d) => d.x).y((d) => d.y));

    // 建置節點
    const nodes = svg
        .selectAll('.node')
        .data(nodesData.descendants())
        .join('g')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`)
        .on('click', nodeClick);

    // 建置節點圓圈
    nodes
        .append('circle')
        .style('fill', (d) => d.data.color)
        .style('stroke', 'black')
        .style('stroke-width', (d) => (d.children || d._children) ? 0 : 2)
        .attr('r', 10);

    // 建置文字
    nodes
        .append('text')
        .attr('dx', '.9em')
        .style('font-size', '12px')
        .text((d) => d.data.name);

    // 建置文字的描述 滑鼠移到節點上 顯示描述
    nodes
        .filter((d) => d.data.description)
        .append('title')
        .text((d) => d.data.description);

    // 拖拉與縮放樹圖
    function zoomed(event) {
        svg.attr('transform', `translate(${event.transform.x - 300}, ${event.transform.y + 20}) scale(${event.transform.k})`);
    }

    // 切換節點展開
    function toggleCollapse(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
        update(d);
    }

    // 節點點擊事件處理
    function nodeClick(event, d) {
        if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
            toggleCollapse(d);
        }
    }

    // 更新節點
    function update(source) {
        // 更新節點和線的資料
        const nodes = nodesData.descendants();
        const links = nodesData.links();

        // 更新線
        const link = svg.selectAll('.link').data(links);

        link.exit().remove();

        link
            .enter()
            .insert('path', ':first-child')
            .attr('class', 'link')
            .merge(link)
            .attr('d', d3.linkVertical().x((d) => d.x).y((d) => d.y));

        // 更新節點
        const node = svg.selectAll('.node').data(nodes, (d) => d.data.name);

        node.exit().remove();

        const nodeEnter = node
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'node')
            .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
            .on('click', nodeClick);

        // 節點外圍邊框 若沒有子節點，給節點邊框
        nodeEnter
            .append('circle')
            .attr('r', 11)
            .style('fill', 'none');

        // 節點圓圈
        nodeEnter
            .append('circle')
            .style('fill', (d) => d.data.color)
            .style('stroke', 'black')
            .style('stroke-width', (d) => (d.children || d._children) ? 0 : 2)
            .attr('r', 10);

        // 文字
        nodeEnter
            .append('text')
            .attr('dx', '.9em')
            .style('font-size', '12px')
            .text((d) => d.data.name);

        // 文字的描述 滑鼠移到節點上 顯示描述
        nodeEnter
            .filter((d) => d.data.description)
            .append('title')
            .text((d) => d.data.description);

        const nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

        nodeUpdate
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`);
    }

    // 更新節點
    update(nodesData);
```

Comment: Do you wish to make spacing between sibling nodes variable? If so, the standard D3 tree layout is not suitable